# It's you who are/is different

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammaticality-in-context

A: You've changed.
B: No, it's you who has/have changed.

I'm not sure about whether we use the 'singular' or 'plural' in this type of sentence.

More example sentences:
"It's you who is/are different."
"It's you who need/needs us."

Comment: This question has been asked at least a few times already, but I'm not sure if any of them have definitive enough answers? https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75126 https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/228626 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57954

Comment: Most of the existing answers are wrong, partial or misleading.  I'll post a new one.

Comment: Nothing to do with singular or plural; use the form appropriate to 'you'.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, as others have said here and in previous answers to similar questions, "you" is the pronoun that determines the number of the following verb, hence:

"It's you who have changed."

In colloquial usage, "It's you who's changed" is very common, and most native speakers wouldn't see anything wrong with it.

NGrams [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+you+who+have%2Cit%27s+you+who%27ve%2Cit%27s+you+who+has%2Cit%27s+you+who%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).

Comment: This is exactly what got me confused in the first place. A native speaker said that even though it's grammatically incorrect but in conversational English people say- "It's you who has changed"/ "It's you who is mistaken."/ "It's you who is different."

Comment: Ashraf, there are varying degrees of incorrectness. Some constructions like "It's you who has changed" are incorrect, but will pass the notice of many native speakers. Native speakers make mistakes all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct choices are:

"It's you who have changed."
"It's you who are different."
"It's you who need us."

The verb in the relative clause must agree with the antecedent: "It is I who am generous."

Comment: "It is I who am generous." Never heard anyone say 'who am.' Sounds really odd.